# i want to make a sentence that express about confidence

Tags: expressions

Nice to meet you.
I want to speak use easy word and be natural.

the situation like it.
i'm good at running. But there are many people who is run better.
so i want to say that "you guys run very well. so i ____________"

there are some examples i made...

1. so i have no confidence to run (i think it is not natural...)
2. so i feel dispirited to run (but "dispirited" little hard word..)

maybe.. there are some wrong grammar. but please let it slide!

Comment: Hello! You may be interested in [ell.se] if you are learning English

Comment: I was going to make the same suggestion. One expression you could use is _I can't compete with you_, meaning that if you _did_ enter a competition with them you would be certain to lose.

Comment: Maybe you could say something like, "You guys run much better than I do, so I'm going to take  pass (that is, not run with you)."

Comment: You could say "... so I feel outclassed".